# Using CSS, Locate at TextBox by it's upper right corner

Tags: css, asp.net

I'm progressively learning CSS and I have a layout where I want to have a series of textboxes where the user inputs data. I'd like to have the labels to the left and the textbox on the right with the label right aligned and the text box left aligned. In the desktop publishing world, this would easily be done with right tabs. Right tab then label, left tab then text box.

In CSS I can easily align the textboxes using left and top tags. But how do I deal with lining up the labels on the left side? Each label is a different length, so the upper left corner will all be different.

The only solution I have thought of is to make all the labels controls the same width and right align the text internally. Then the upper lefts can be used.

Is there some way to align the upper right of a control?

**************** Edited ****************
The code is just a list of controls;

```html
            <div class="DeliveryReport">
                <telerik:RadLabel ID="rlbStartDate" runat="server" Text="Start Date:" CssClass="rlbStartDate"></telerik:RadLabel>
                <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpStartDate" runat="server" CssClass="rdpStartDate"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                <telerik:RadLabel ID="rlbEndDate" runat="server" Text="End Date:" CssClass="rlbEndDate"></telerik:RadLabel>
                <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="rdpEndDate" runat="server" CssClass="rdpEndDate"></telerik:RadDatePicker>
                <telerik:RadLabel ID="rlbPartNumbers" runat="server" Text="Part Number:" CssClass="rlbPartNumbers"></telerik:RadLabel>
                <telerik:RadComboBox ID="rcbPartNumbers" runat="server" CssClass="rcbPartNumbers"></telerik:RadComboBox>
                <telerik:RadButton ID="rbtnGetData" runat="server" Text="Get Data" CssClass="rbtnGetData" OnClick="rbtnGetData_Click" AutoPostBack="true"></telerik:RadButton>
                <asp:GridView ID="gvData" runat="server" CssClass="gvData"></asp:GridView>
            </div>
```

```css
.DeliveryReport {
    position: absolute;
    padding-left: 20px;
/*    background-color: yellow;*/
    width: 1000px;
    height: 2000px;
}

    .DeliveryReport .rlbStartDate {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: right;
        width: 120px;
        Left: 20px;
        top: 5px;
    }
    .DeliveryReport .rdpStartDate {
        position: absolute;
        left: 150px;
        top: 0px;
    }
    .DeliveryReport .rlbEndDate {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: right;
        width: 120px;
        Left: 20px;
        top: 55px;
    }
    .DeliveryReport .rdpEndDate {
        position: absolute;
        left: 150px;
        top: 50px;
    }
    .DeliveryReport .rlbPartNumbers {
        position: absolute;
        text-align: right;
        width: 120px;
        Left: 20px;
        top: 105px;
    }
    .DeliveryReport .rcbPartNumbers {
        position: absolute;
        left: 150px;
        top: 100px;
    }
    .DeliveryReport .rbtnGetData {
        position: absolute;
        left: 420px;
        top: 50px;
    }
    .DeliveryReport .gvData {
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        top: 150px;
        background-color: aquamarine ;
    }
```

The intent is to get this layout;
[image]

I'm current doing this by setting the three labels to be the same width and then use the same left aligning. I would like to be able to specify the right side location, then I don't have to worry about making then all the same width.

Comment: Please show us your code. The HTML structure is important to help us find a proper solution. Having said that, have you looked at the CSS right property?

Comment: Have you considered creating a div around each set (label and input) and styling based on that div, you could create one class that would apply to all your inputs.